# how to rotate different part of canvas separately in android

Tags: android, canvas, view, rotation

i have custom view that contains many rectangles and ovals and ..... i can rotate my whole canvas(rect and ovals and ....) by using canvas.Rotate(degree,cneterX,centerY)

but in bottom of the my view i want to have a something like menu that doesn't rotate when i use canvas.rotate() . it means that i want to rotate these rectangles and ovals but don't wanna rotate my menu that will be create with same canvas.

```
@Override 
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    float ringWidth = textHeight + 4; 
    int height = getMeasuredHeight(); 
    int width =getMeasuredWidth(); 

    int px = width; 
    int py = height/2; 
    Point center = new Point(px,py ); 

    int radius = Math.max(px, py)-2; 

    int UpperSide = center.y;

    RectF boundingBox = new RectF(center.x - radius,  center.y - radius, center.x + radius, center.y + radius); 

    RectF innerBoundingBox = new RectF(center.x - radius , center.y - radius , center.x + radius, center.y + radius ); 


    RectF GroundSectionBox = new RectF(center.x - radius,UpperSide ,center.x + radius,center.y + radius);

    RectF RightPanel = new RectF(center.x + width -(width/4), center.y - (radius/2)+10, center.x+radius- ringWidth, center.y + (radius/2)-10);
    RectF LeftPanel = new RectF(center.x - radius + ringWidth ,center.y - (radius/2)+10, center.x - width + (width/4), center.y + (radius/2)-10);

    RectF RightBlack = new RectF(center.x + width -(width/4),center.y-(radius/10),center.x+radius- ringWidth,center.y + (radius/10));
    RectF leftBlack = new RectF(center.x - radius + ringWidth ,center.y - (radius/10), center.x - width + (width/4), center.y + (radius/10));

        .
        .
    canvas.drawRect(innerBoundingBox, groundPaint);

    canvas.drawPath(skyPath, skyPaint);     
    canvas.drawRect(GroundSectionBox, skyPaint);

    canvas.drawPath(skyPath, markerPaint);

    canvas.drawRect(RightBlack, sideBlack);
    canvas.drawRect(leftBlack, sideBlack);


    canvas.drawRect(RightPanel, RightPanelup);
    canvas.drawRect(LeftPanel, LeftPanelUp);
        .
        .
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cans use the save and restore methods on Canvas to draw stuff in transformations, then restore back to the original state. Here's an example:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
     canvas.save(); // Canvas is in original state. Save it before anything

     // Perform any transformations you want here (like rotate)
     // Draw while your transformations are in place (like ovals) 

     canvas.restore(); // Canvas state returned to what it was when you called save

     // Draw things that need to be drawn without any transformations
}
```

Hope this helps :)